# php filtering function for jquery table

Tags: php

I use jquery datatables in server side processing and I try to implement in php a function for my Global Filter:

Function should display all rows **only if and only if**:

---

-- both words are in the same column AND in the same row
OR
-- both words are in different columns AND in the same row

---

So..If I type `floor free` or `free floor` on Global Filter it should returns always the SAME query.

You can test Global Filter here but this table don't load data from MySQL and I want replicate this client side filtering in php: [DEMO](http://datatables.altervista.org/yadcf_client/127.0.0.1/yadcf/dimensioni%20corrette%20importante%20anche%20css%20yadcf%20filter%20-%20css.html)

Instead, in my server side table relevant php code which controls Global Filter is:

```
    static function filter ( $request, $columns, &$bindings )
{
    $globalSearch = array();
    $columnSearch = array();
    $dtColumns = self::pluck( $columns, 'dt' );

    if ( isset($request['search']) && $request['search']['value'] != '' ) {
        $str = $request['search']['value'];

        for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
            $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
            $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
            $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

            if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' ) {
                $binding = self::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                //$globalSearch[] = "match(".$column['db'].") against (".$binding.")";
                $globalSearch[] = "`".$column['db']."` LIKE ".$binding;
            }
        }
    }
```

What should i do?
I believe that I do explode the search string into separate words:

```
$words = explode(' ', $str);
$wordcount = count($words);
```

and then my condition should look like:

```
WHERE IF(Column1 LIKE '%{$words[0]}%' OR Column2 LIKE '%{$words[0]}%' OR Column4 LIKE '%{$words[0]}%', 1, 0)
+ IF(Column1 LIKE '%{$words[1]}%' OR Column2 LIKE '%{$words[1]}%' OR Column4 LIKE '%{$words[1]}%', 1, 0)
+ IF(Column1 LIKE '%{$words[2]}%' OR Column2 LIKE '%{$words[2]}%' OR Column4 LIKE '%{$words[2]}%', 1, 0)
+ ...
    >= $wordcount
```

Each of the IF expressions should be 1 if that word is found in any of the columns. Adding them together will get the total number of words found in any column. Then test if this is at least the number of words (it could be more if the same word is in multiple columns).

But I don't understand how to use *nested foreach loops* to build the query from your input. Also I don't understand If I must use [Table API](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think I have an idea. But be careful it's untested. The function should var_dump an SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE 
CONCAT(column1, column2, column3) LIKE '%free%' AND
CONCAT(column1, column2, column3) LIKE '%floor%'
```

Concat joins the 3 given columns to one (you can concat as many columns as you want)

```
function filter ( $request, $columns, &$bindings )
{
    $globalSearch = array();
    $columnSearch = array();
    $dtColumns = self::pluck( $columns, 'dt' );

    if ( isset($request['search']) && $request['search']['value'] != '' ) {
        $string = $request['search']['value'];
        $string = split(" ", $string);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";
        $j = 0;
        foreach($string as $str){
            $concat = "CONCAT(";
            for ( $i=0, $ien=count($request['columns']) ; $i<$ien ; $i++ ) {
                $requestColumn = $request['columns'][$i];
                $columnIdx = array_search( $requestColumn['data'], $dtColumns );
                $column = $columns[ $columnIdx ];

                if ( $requestColumn['searchable'] == 'true' ) {
                    //$binding = self::bind( $bindings, '%'.$str.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR );
                    //$globalSearch[] = "match(".$column['db'].") against (".$binding.")";
                    $globalSearch[] = $column['db'];
                }
            }
            $concat .= implode(",", $globalSearch) . ") LIKE '%" . $str . "%'";
            if($j > 0 ){
                $query .= " AND " . $concat;
            }else{
                $query .= $concat;
            }
            $globalSeach = array();
            $j++
        }
        var_dump($query);
    }
}
```

I hope my code can help you a little bit.

Comment: Sorry for late reply Florian. Your sql query is working good on my mysql database and display data correctly. But your php code adaptation doesn't work. The table is not even shown. Something is wrong in php code.

Comment: yes, but something inside is wrong because when I replace my global filter code with your solution code inside ssp.class.php something crash my table and query string is not building. I replace `table` with my table name. Look my default php code, please: https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/206 - How can I edit it including your code correctly?

Comment: With your code my table is not loaded, page is blank with column name only. I don't know which line because I simply replace my ncode in this question with your. Have you need offline project? I try everything but unsuccesfully

Comment: Pleas turn on error reporting. Put this on the first line: 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?>`

Comment: error: `DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1` -- [DEMO](http://datatables.altervista.org/yadcf_server/yadcf2/yadcf2/examples/server_side/simple2.html)

Comment: i think the error don't come from the filter() function I posted.
If you go to [this site](http://datatables.altervista.org/yadcf_server/yadcf2/yadcf2/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing1.php)
there are other php errors.

Comment: Dear Florian, can you help me to solve the problem directly from my site, please? Is very important for me. Go to [THIS](https://aa.altervista.org/index.php?client_id=altervista&response_type=code&lang=it&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fit.altervista.org%2Fcplogin.php) site and insert [THIS](http://pastebin.com/kfEet7E1) credentials. You can edit php files. Feel free to apply any changes